# Angular5+Three.js Cannot read property 'Scene1' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, module, three.js

I have an angular5 website integrated with Three.js. When I want to add object to Scene I get the following error: Cannot read property 'Scene1' of undefined. The scene should be defined, any Ideas?

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
public scene = null;
camera = null;
mesh = null;
THREE.Loader.Handlers.add( /\.dds$/i, new THREE.DDSLoader );
var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
            mtlLoader.setPath( '../../assets/obj/' );
            mtlLoader.load( 'SkyboxSky.mtl', function( materials ) {
                materials.preload();
                var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
                objLoader.setMaterials( materials );
                objLoader.setPath( '../../assets/obj/' );
                objLoader.load( 'SkyboxSky.obj', function ( object ) {
                    object.position.y = 0;
                    this.scene.add( object );
                }, onProgress, onError );
            });
```

But if some sample object is added after this, there is no problem in adding it to the scene.

Comment: I would guess that this is an async error of some kind, and that the scene isn't built before you're attempting to add the object.

Comment: That makes sense, but do you know then how to wait for loading to finish? Is there maybe await-ish function? I tried setting up scene like      `scene = new THREE.Scene();` right before that line of code, with no success.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer(); 
public scene = null; 
camera = null; 
mesh = null;
this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
var scope = this;
THREE.Loader.Handlers.add( /\.dds$/i, new THREE.DDSLoader ); 
var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader(); 
mtlLoader.setPath( '../../assets/obj/' ); 
mtlLoader.load( 'SkyboxSky.mtl', function( materials ) { 
    materials.preload(); 
    var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader(); 
    objLoader.setMaterials( materials ); 
    objLoader.setPath( '../../assets/obj/' ); 
    objLoader.load( 'SkyboxSky.obj', function ( object ) { 
        object.position.y = 0; 
        scope.scene.add( object ); 
    }, onProgress, onError ); 
});
```

Comment: I found the issue. The issue was that angular was not installed properly